# Get Years months days hours minutes from moment from duration

Tags: react-native, momentjs

```
const seconds = 1000000

var now = moment(moment.duration(seconds).asSeconds()).format('Y[y],M[m],D[d],H[h]')
```

I want to format this seconds to years, months, days,hours,minutes so I am not able to get where I am making mistake how can I get this format in React native

Answer (score 0):

this code might help you

```
export function formatDate(seconds) {
   var d = new Date(seconds*1000),
   month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
   day = '' + d.getDate(),
   year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) 
      month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) 
      day = '0' + day;

  return [day,month,year].join('/');
}
```

this code will return you dd/mm/yyyy. if you want to return date+time then you simply return

```
export function formatDate(seconds) {
   var d = new Date(seconds*1000)
    return d.toLocaleString()
}
```

if you want to get remains time, day, month and year then you should use this code

```js
function secondsToHms(sec) {
    sec = Number(sec);
    var y = Math.floor(sec/31536000) //<<years
    var w= Math.floor(y*31536000)
    var w1=Math.floor(w-sec)
    w=Math.floor(Math.abs(w1)/604800)//<<weeks
    var d=Math.floor(Math.abs(w)*604800)
    var d1=Math.floor(Math.abs(d)-Math.abs(w1))
    d=Math.floor(Math.abs(d1)/86400)
    d=Math.abs(d)                //<<day
    var h = Math.floor(d*86400);
    h=Math.floor(h-Math.abs(d1))
    h=Math.floor(Math.abs(h)/3600)//<<hours
    var m = Math.floor(sec % 3600 / 60);//<<minutes
    var s = Math.floor(sec % 3600 % 60);//<<seconds
  
    var yDisplay = y > 0 ? y + (y == 1 ? " year, " : " years, ") : "0 year, ";
    var wDisplay = w > 0 ? w + (w == 1 ? " week, " : " weeks, ") : "0 week, ";
    var dDisplay = d > 0 ? d + (d == 1 ? " day, " : " days, ") : "0 day, ";
    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "0 hour, ";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "0 minute, ";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second. " : " seconds. ") : "0 second. ";

    return yDisplay + wDisplay + dDisplay + hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay;
  }
  console.log(secondsToHms(1000000))
```

Comment: Hi @shammi I do not want it like this I want to divide. like 48 minutes so I want it into 0 years,0 months, 0 days, 0 hours, 48 minutes  like this.

Comment: oh ok. wait i will write a new code for you please wait for a while

Comment: I found this in moment .format('Y[y],M[m],D[d]') this is working in react js but not working on React native if you know about it

Comment: I think something went wrong with the moment. I wrote a code for you please try it and let me know.